# How to join to the results of another query

Tags: linq-to-sql

I first need to query a table of people to find all the families I want.  This query does the job nicely:  (from m in Members where m.Lastname.StartsWith("A") select m.FamilyID).Distinct()

The above returns me a short list of FamilyIDs (integer).  I need Distinct because a family can have more than one member.

How do I then join this list to another table to retrieve all rows in that second table where a column called FamilyID whose values are in the first list?

Is there something like IN in Transact-SQL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Linq to sql has the `Contains` that does something similar. It is just really the other way around in syntax so you need to get used to it but it works like a charm.

Have a look here http://wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/